# InPlaceEditor JQUERY

Tags: jquery

Currently I implementing this plugin

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/

I have some minor problems with it.

Currently to edit the element is by means of clicking on it. Now I want it edit it (change the label to text box) when I click the edit button on the right of the page.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In looking at the code for that plugin, the `click` is what triggers the inline edit. So you should be able to trigger it with your button

```
$(function(){
  var input=$('.myInputSelector').editInPlace({
    //editInPlace settings
  });
  $('.myButton').click(function(){
    input.click();
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried out this code, and it works fine... but when i click on the anchor with the anchor class myInputSelector, its still shows the editInPlace options.. I want to bind this action only on the button click, and not on clicking the selector.. is there a way that i can do this..

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use a onClick function when clicking on the edit button, this function should be the same as onClick in the label. If javascript is making that automaticly, you can check the code and see wich function is applied to the clicked text and use that one to your edit button